# web components snapshot test

Tags: javascript, web, components, jestjs

Given this custom component:

```js
const style = `
  div {
    color: red;
  }
`;

const html = `
  <div>
    SAMPLE WEB COMPONENT
  </div>
`;

const $element = document.createElement('template');
$element.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    ${style}
  </style>
  ${html}
`;

export default class Sample extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.root = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    this.root.appendChild($element.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
```

Is there any chance of having snapshot tests using Jest? Using something like jest-snapshot-serializer-raw or jsdom + serializer or other.

Comment: interesting question. jsdom seems to [support shadow DOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2347) but I have not found anything specific in their docs

Comment: looking into https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/895 I'm wondering if `document.getElementById(...).shadowRoot` may provide you with access and you could serialize that as you do with ordinary HTML fragments(btw don't know any serializer for that, do you?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question and all it took was getting the WebComponent in a serialized way (innerHTML) and checking the snapshot on that:

```
it('should render correctly', () => {
    const myComponent = new MyComponent();

    expect(myComponent.innerHTML).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```